# why is it not allowed to take aspirin based medicines before a day and after a week of cataract surgery?

Tags: eye, surgery, ophthalmology

my mom had a cataract surgery she used to take daily dosage of UNISTAR 75 which contains aspirin in it but doctor said not to take it for a week. what is the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aspirin has a "blood thinning" effect; it inhibits platelet aggregation. Therefore, it gives a higher risk of bleeding in the period surrounding the surgery.

I have not found a review about specifically cataract surgery, but [this](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1401105#t=article) large trial (>10000 patients) shows that in noncardiac surgeries, aspirin gives an increased risk of major bleeding.